# How to pass a method a List<Interface> instead of List<Class>?

Tags: java, oop, collections, interface

I have some objects that implement a common interface. Let's say I have `Apple` and some other `Fruits` that implement `HasSeed` and return their number of seeds.

I then have a service method, call it `FruitProcessor` here, with an `addAll(List<HasSeed>)` class. I thought I then can pass in a list of objects that implement the `HasSeed` interface, like a list of apples.

But I can't and the compiler complains that it's not applicable for the arguments.
One more thing: I cannot change the `List<Apple>` to a `List<HasSeed>`. BUT I need a method in my FruitProcessor that can take any list of objects, and then calls `getSeeds()` no matter what object it is.

How could I adapt the following?

```
class Fruit {};
class Apple extends Fruit implements HasSeed {
   @Override
   int getSeeds() {
       return 5; //just an example
   }
}

class FruitProcessor {
    static void addAll(List<HasSeed> list) {
        for (HasSeed seed : list) {
            Sysout("the fruit added contained seeds: " + list.getSeeds());
        }
    }
}

class FruitStore {
    List<Apple> apples;
    FruitProcessor.addAll(apples); //The method addAll(List<HasSeed>) in the type FruitProcessor is not applicable for the arguments (List<Apple>)
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use `List<? extends HasSeed>`

The reason behind is that `List<Apple>` doesn't extend `List<HasSeed>`. When you write `List<? extends HasSeed>` in your signature it means you accept any list of elements that implements the `HasSeed` interface. Which is why you can pass `List<Apple>` as a `List<? extends HasSeed>`

Comment: What about `private <T extends HasSeed> List<T> doSomething(List<T> arg)` ? why it doesn't work as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `static void addAll(List<? extends HasSeed> list)` since you declared your list as a `List<Apple>` and not `List<HasSeed>`.